# How can I import customers from Umbraco CMS to Magento with passwords

Tags: c#, php, magento, umbraco, umbraco7

I need to import all the customers from Umbraco CMS with uCommerce to Magento store. The problem I have is that Umbraco stores the passwords hashed using HMACSHA-256 algorithm, but Magento uses SHA-256 algorithm.

So, there is no way to retrieve raw passwords from Umbraco, only hashes. The only one idea I have is to change a Magento hash algorithm to the same Umbraco uses. Is that possible?

Did you do something similar? What can you suggest?

Comment: `So, there is no way to retrieve raw passwords from Umbraco, only hashes.` - and that is how it should be! As you already said, changing the has-algorithm in Magento is your only solution...

Comment: Out of curriosity, why are you migrating away ?

Comment: it's just a wish of my client. I don't know their reason. @MortenSkjoldager

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't (easily, at least) extract the passwords into plain-text and change over.

One option is to have two separate password columns, legacy and new. Legacy holds the existing HMACSHA-256, and new holds the SHA-256 hash. When a user logs in, check the password against the legacy hash, and if it works run the password they've provided against a SHA-256 hashing method, store it in the new password column. Over time, your users will migrate the passwords over to your new hashing algorithm.